# HIbernate Encrypting and Decrypting in Getters/Setters?

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, grails-orm

The problem is to provide ability to encrypt certain Entity attributes.

Since the Entities are groovy classes and generated at run time, I had incorporated the 
encryption logic in the setter and decryption logic in the getter. But It seems hibernate expects Getter/Setter to be symmetric. The session.save() calls the getter to set the value internally and hence it always saves the decrypted version to the database.

Is this Hibernate's Default behavior? Is there some way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are you using annotations? If yes, where are you placing your annotation? On the GETTERs/SETTERs or on the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to do some munging between what's in the database and what's in the persistent entity, the way to do this is to use a [custom user type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom). I've used it for things like making sure strings that get saved are padded with spaces. It's a lot less intrusive than adding code to getters and setters, and you avoid problems with accidental saves caused by Hibernate thinking you've made changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GORM events here.  Do the encryption before database insert in

```
def beforeInsert() {
  if (encProperty != null) {
     encProperty = customEncrypt(encProperty)
  }
}
```

and decrypt after reading from db:

```
def afterLoad() {
  if (encProperty != null)
      encProperty = customDecrypt(encProperty )
```

}

Use `def beforeUpdate()` for encrypting during update.

Reference:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping